# 1. Launch app by broadcastreceiver ; 2. Custom caller id

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have two questions:

1. I would like that my broadcastreceiver will be the mainlauncher (not activity !!). How to do it?
2. I would like to write a custom incoming call window / custom caller id. How can I replace the default window or hide it with mine?

Ariel

Comment: please explore the things before asking..!

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast receiver cannot be used as a main launcher i.e. an activity.

The broadcast receiver will just listen for Intents in the background (app doesn't need to be running). When you receive a broadcast intent you then perform an action based on the type of broadcast.

For example, in what you want to do, you would have the broadcast receiver listen for phone state changed and check whether its incoming and then launch an activity within your app.

Note, I am not sure whether you have access to change the incoming call window as this is controlled by android internally and I don't believe you have access to not use this or amend  the window.